# override or implement a supertype method [ERROR]

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I am trying to create a OnItemClick method to launch another activity from my ListView. I am receiving  multiple error once the method is created. the error messages are:

1. The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) of type LoginList must override or implement a supertype method
2. The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type FragmentActivity

   I have tried implementing another method (below) but receive similar errors.I Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong. examples help most

Method: public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)

Here is my Class:

```
public class LoginList extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private ListView loginList;
private Button webLogin;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;



@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);

loginList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.loginlist);
loginList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

webLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
webLogin.setOnClickListener(this);


//Specify fileds to display in the list
String[] from = new String[] { ListProvider.COLUMN_NAME_SITE };

//Bind fields to listview
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.nameView };

// Create CursorAdapter and set it to display
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, from, to);

loginList.setAdapter(adapter);

getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);      
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {  // 1.The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) of type LoginList must override or implement a supertype method

super.onListItemClick (l, v, position, id); //2. The method onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type FragmentActivity

startActivity(new Intent(this, UpdateDeleteLoginList.class)
    .putExtra(ListProvider.COLUMN_ROWID, id));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent webLoginIntent = new Intent (this, LoginPlusActivity.class);
startActivity(webLoginIntent);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int ignored, final Bundle args) {
return new CursorLoader(this, ListProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
adapter.swapCursor(cursor); 
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset (Loader<Cursor> loader) {
adapter.swapCursor(null);

}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right imports? Press Ctrl+Shift+O (Organize imports) in Eclipse to import all necessary types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extend FragmentActivity but don't make use of fragments.

You have 2 options:

1st create fragment extending [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) and this is were You implement onClick methods

2nd extend [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) instead

Comment: Thank for reply. I have implemented sugesstion 1. now since FragmentActivity is not extended I receive a getLoaderManager() error. " The method getSupportLoaderManager() is undefined for the type LoginList ". any advice?

Comment: To make use of LoaderManager in api <11 You have to use support library and fragments. So You have to go with first solution or change min api to 11

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by choosing the right import (android.view.View.OnClickListener). I had imported the "android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener" and that gave me the samme error.